# How to make custom css button responsive?

Tags: css, button, responsive-design

I have created a CSS button but it is not responsive. I have tried adding `EM or %` but still not working. I want to change *width* and *height* according to the screen resolution.

Following is the CSS code I am actually using:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:480px) { }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <p>
      <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1a">Click Here To Enter The Future</button> 
   </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
  font-size:0.875em;
  display:block;
  left:-60px;
  margin-top:35px;
}
```

Right now the button is moving from left to right, but I want the button to appear at the exact same place.

Answer (score 22):

You could add `width:100%;` to achieve your objective.

[image]

```
.btn {
      font-size:0.875em;
      display:block;
      left:-60px;
      margin-top:35px;
      width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: I am starting this new trend on SO to use lots of animation answers.

Comment: So, Which tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
.btn {
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 50px;  // add this if you want
   max-width: 300px; // add this if  you want, adjust accordingly
}
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible to control the size of the flex boxes without padding?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#select_preferences').multiselect({
        buttonText: function(options, select) {
            return 'Look for users that:';
        },
        buttonTitle: function(options, select) {
            var labels = [];
            options.each(function() {
                labels.push($(this).text()); //get the options in a string. later it would be joined with - seprate between each.
            });
         if(!labels.length ===0 )
        {
         $('#range-div').removeClass('hide');
         // The class 'hide' hide the content.
         //So I remove it so it would be visible.
        }
        if (labels.length ===0)
         $('#range-div').addClass('hide');
     //If the labels array is empty - then do use the hide class to hide the range-selector.
            return labels.join(' - ');
    // the options seperated by ' - '
    // This returns the text of th options in labels[].
        }
    });
```